# Error 'Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_48: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2' when adding Conv1D layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to construct the following model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim = num_top_words, output_dim = 64, input_length = input_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

But I get the following error when running it:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_48: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

which points out that there is an error at the following line:

```
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu'))
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: post your code where you process and pass the data

Comment: @ryekos:Try to put `model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(model.output, axis=-1)))`  right before the `LSTM` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that currently the output shape of `LSTM` layer is `(None, 100)`, however, as the error suggests, `Conv1D` layer like `LSTM` layer expects a 3D input of shape `(None, n_steps, n_features)`. So one way to resolve this is to pass `return_sequences=True` to LSTM layer to have the output of each timestep and therefore its output would be 3D:

```
model.add(LSTM(100, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=True))
```

Alternatively, you can put the `Conv1D` and `MaxPooling1D` layers before the `LSTM` layer (which may be even better than the current architecture, since one usage of `Conv1D` plus pooling layers is to reduce the dimension of LSTM layer's input and hence reduce the computational complexity):

```
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(LSTM(100, activation = 'relu'))
```